# Redirect current user

Tags: users, redirect

The following line ist out of an plugin. In this line if settings are set the current unsers /without admin) will be redirectet to profile page.

How is it possible to tell the sytem, that it should only redirect subscribers ?

```
$update['redirect_user']            = ($current['redirect_user'])?$current['redirect_user']:1;
```

Iam further not shure if this is possible to define in this line. if not, where could it be ?

Comment: Can you provide more context? This is just assigning a value to an array index without more information it's going to be very hard to provide any sort of helpful answer.

Comment: $user = wp_get_current_user(); $role = $user->roles ? $user->roles[0] : false;